# Game Development: How to add acceleration to velocity?

Tags: android, math, game-physics, game-development, acceleration

I have a View which I need to scale with an acceleration, I mean, that when the scale is `MIN_SCALE`, the velocity must be slow, but when the scale is near of `MAX_SALE`, the velocity must be more fast. Now my velocity is always the same.

There is a number of frames that the View will use to do it's movement:

```
numberOfFrames = Math.round((float)ANIMATION_TIME/GameLoopThread.FRAME_PERIOD);
frameCount = 0;
```

and I calculate the scaleVelocity with that number of frames:

```
scaleVelocity = (MAX_SCALE-MIN_SCALE)/numberOfFrames;
```

Each game loop iteration, I update the scale of the view with this code:

```
if (frameCount<numberOfFrames) {
    currentScale = currentScale + scaleVelocity;
    frameCount++;
}
```

When frame count has reached the `numberOfFrames` the animation must end.

How can I add acceleration to this code? take in mind that the acceleration must respect that the view needs to reach the `MAX_SCALE` at last frame from the frameCount variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: screenshot from android docs]

Define your interpolator

```
INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateInterpolator();
```

while calculating scaleVelocity, get current interpolated value

```
float interpolatedValue = INTERPOLATOR.getInterpolation(frameCount / numberOfFrames);
```

getInterpolation() returns a value between 0(start of animation) and 1(end anim)

```
scaleVelocity = (MAX_SCALE-MIN_SCALE)/numberOfFrames * interpolatedValue;  // use min,max func if needed.
```

mathematical equation of accelerate interpolator is f(x) = x², if you want greater change then create your custom interpolator.

working test method for animation.

```
 private void testAnim() {
    int numberOfFrames = 100;//Math.round((float)ANIMATION_TIME/GameLoopThread.FRAME_PERIOD);
    float frameCount = 0;
    float MAX_SCALE = 4;
    float MIN_SCALE = 0.1f;
    float scaleVelocity;
    float currentScale ;
    Interpolator INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateInterpolator();

    do {
        float interpolatedValue = INTERPOLATOR.getInterpolation(frameCount / numberOfFrames);
        scaleVelocity = (MAX_SCALE - MIN_SCALE) * interpolatedValue;

        currentScale = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, scaleVelocity);
        ++frameCount;
        Log.d("STACK", "testAnim: currentScale = " + currentScale);
        // apply scale to view.
    } while (frameCount < numberOfFrames);

    // finally set final value of animation.
    currentScale = MAX_SCALE;
    // apply scale to view.

}
```

Comment: thank you but if I do your logic, it gives a scale between 0.1 and 1.4, something is not working because my MIN_SCALE is 0.1 and MAX_SCALE is 4.0

Comment: I have edited my answer that includes working test method which provides scale values from MIN_SCALE to MAX_SCALE.

Comment: I finally solve it using this formula:
currentScale = ((MAX_SCALE-MIN_SCALE)*(scaleInterpolator.getInterpolation((float)(frameCount+1)/numberOfFrames)))+MIN_SCALE;

Comment: what do you think about my formula?

Comment: that is same logic, except you are adding MIN_SCALE (=0.1)to every frame, you can also try different interpolators.

Comment: i added MIN_SCALE because if not, always tops in 3.9 instead of 4. Is correct to add it?

Comment: Oh yes, I actually ran the code and we need to actually add MIN_SCALE instead of using Math.max(), because we need to animate from MIN_SCALE to MAX_SCALE.

Comment: in your formula,( frameCount+1) is not required, if we stop loop at ( frameCount<=numberOfFrame), it will save an addition op in every loop